# Missing and missed

Tags: past-participles, present-participles

What's the difference between **your missing friend** and **your missed friend**?
What do these two sentences mean?

miss: to fail to be or go somewhere

If I want to express that my friend has disappeared and I can't find it, Can I say my missed friend?

So does missed mean it can't be found now or it has disappeared?

If I am missing you is correct, does your missing friend mean your friend is missd by you?

Comment: Have you consulted a dictionary?  Those adjectives have different meanings which a dictionary should make clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Missing**: **(of a thing) not able to be found because it is not in its expected place.**
"

> My dog went **missing** after I left the gate open"

**feel regret or sadness at no longer being able to enjoy the presence of.**

> "She was very **missed** by her friends"

Comment: miss: to fail to be or go somewhere

If I want to express that my friend has disappeared and I can't find it, Can I say my missed friend?

So does missed mean it can't be found now or it has disappeared?

If I am missing you is correct, does your missing friend mean your friend is missd by you?

Comment: No. If your friend has disappeared, you would say "He went missing" or "my friend is missing" meaning that he disappeared and nobody can find him.

Comment: Missing is an adjective not a verb in that context. You can say whatever you want but some things won't translate into English well. Try to look for things English speakers say instead of trying to adapt your language to English. Instead of saying "My missed friend" say "My very good friend who I haven't seen in a while". Ask for expressions on the forum try to sound as natural as possible.